# Have a Json format response from URL with using WCF Rest

Tags: c#, json, wcf

I want to get WCF Json request fron URL with POST method.When I invoke the function in C#, I take correct request but when I write the function to url, ı cannot take correct result. Can someone help me please ?

### This is my Service1.svc File

```
 public string ChangePassword(string jsonString) // sample function
    {
        // sample input string = {"email":"anilkilic93@hotmail.com","password":"123456"}

        LoginInformations person1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginInformations>(jsonString);

        person1.password = "654321"; // password was changed

        string returnJsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person1);

        return returnJsonString;

    }
```

This is My IService1.svc File

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "ChangePassword/{jsonString}")]
     string ChangePassword(string jsonString);
```

This is my web.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>



  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web" >
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="MyServiceApplication.Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyServiceApplication.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="FoodRecommendationDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ANIL-BILGISAYAR\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=FoodRecommendationDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
  </entityFramework>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can You show Your incorrect result?

Comment: I edited and I added picture , you can show incorrect result

Answer (score 0):

You should change an interface to

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "ChangePassword")]
LoginInformations ChangePassword(LoginInformations loginInformations);
```

And sent json as body but not as query parameter.

Otherwise You can split login and password and send it separatelly as query parameters but it is not recommended (easy to steal Your credentials)

Comment: can u give an example about how ı can call in Url  ? (for example http://localhost:54940/Service1.svc/Changepassword   like this ?)

Comment: @AnilKilic, yep, You also should send a body, so You need use some application like fiddler or plugin for browser, etc

Answer (score 0):

please try this in your `IService1.svc` File

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
   RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
   UriTemplate = "ChangePassword")]
LoginInformations ChangePassword(LoginInformations loginInformations);

[DataContract]
public class LoginInformations
{
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Password { set; get; }
}
```

and this in your `Service1.svc` file

```
    public LoginInformations ChangePassword(LoginInformations loginInformations)
    {
        try
        {
            loginInformations.Password = "654321";

            return loginInformations;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: now, how can I use this function? Should I call it from url like  http://localhost:54940/Service1.svc/ChangePassword ? how can I send parameter this function from url ? Some people say that I should add fiddler but I don't know how I can do it